# Can we attach an existing Alibaba Cluster (ACK) located in china region in google Anthos?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, google-anthos

We have an existing Alibaba cluster located in China Hangzhou region. When we attach the cluster in Google Cloud Anthos and we are getting an error :   **Unable to connect . please check if GKE Connect Agent is deployed correctly.**

We analyzed and  found out that the cluster was not able to pull the GKE hub agent image from GCR.
We checked all the access to the service account we are using and all required access is in place but the cluster is not able to access the google api.
Can anyone help regarding what can be the possible issues?